# Centering the text in a cell vertically

Tags: tables

I want to center vertically the text in the cell like this:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\begin{longtable}[c]{ |p{7cm}|p{8cm}| } 
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Avantages}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Justification}}} \\
\hline

\endfirsthead

\hline
 Se concentrer sur l’implémentation du plan d’atténuation des vulnérabilités    & Ce plan permet d’assurer que les vulnérabilités sont traitées par des actions spécifiques, mesurables, réalisables, et concrètes. NIST est la seule méthodologie à traiter ce point. \\ \hline
\hline
Aide le testeur à rédiger des rapports périodiques  &  NIST suggère d’écrire un rapport étape par étape, car après chaque planification d’attaque le testeur doit reporter ce qu’il va faire ainsi que les résultats obtenus, ce qui est une bonne pratique si non de nombreux détails tombent dans l’oubli.
\\ \hline
\caption{Les avantages de la méthodologie OSSTMM }
\label{tab:avantages osstmm}
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: You should use `m` columns instead of `p` columns.

Comment: Thank you it did work like magic

Answer (score 4):

You should use `m` columns instead of `p` columns.

Moreover, if you want to avoid the thin white line you have in the first row (in some PDF viewers such as PDF.js used for instance by Firefox), I suggest to try `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{NiceTabular}{m{6cm}X[m]}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=3pt]
  \RowStyle[color=white,rowcolor=black]{\sffamily\large\centering}
  Avantages & Justification \\
  Se concentrer sur l’implémentation du plan d’atténuation des vulnérabilités 
  & Ce plan permet d’assurer que les vulnérabilités sont traitées par des 
  actions spécifiques, mesurables, réalisables, et concrètes. NIST est la seule 
  méthodologie à traiter ce point. \\ 
  Aide le testeur à rédiger des rapports périodiques  
  &  NIST suggère d’écrire un rapport étape par étape, car après chaque planification 
  d’attaque le testeur doit reporter ce qu’il va faire ainsi que les résultats obtenus, 
  ce qui est une bonne pratique si non de nombreux détails tombent dans l’oubli.
  \end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Les avantages de la méthodologie OSSTMM }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 2):

With `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\caption{Les avantages de la méthodologie OSSTMM}
\label{tab:tblr}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {X[0.8,j,m] X[1,j,m]},
             colsep=3pt,
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries, bg=black, fg=white, c}
             }
Avantages   & Justification \\
Se concentrer sur l’implémentation du plan d’atténuation des vulnérabilités
            & Ce plan permet d’assurer que les vulnérabilités sont traitées par des
  actions spécifiques, mesurables, réalisables, et concrètes. NIST est la seule
  méthodologie à traiter ce point. \\
Aide le testeur à rédiger des rapports périodiques
            &  NIST suggère d’écrire un rapport étape par étape, car après chaque planification
  d’attaque le testeur doit reporter ce qu’il va faire ainsi que les résultats obtenus,
  ce qui est une bonne pratique si non de nombreux détails tombent dans l’oubli.
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it's not working for me it does display the table as a text without the borders or anything

Comment: @DidyouknowTHAT, I do not understand your comment. What is not working? If you receive some error in compilation of suggested MWE, pleasetell me what is error. Given MWE in answer works and result is shown in answer. My answer in compare to your code fragment) anticipate standard table in `table` float environment and not long one as can be understand from your code fragment. If this is the problem, you should this emphasize in question and also adding answer tag `longtable`.

Comment: Maybe the OP has written its comment to the wrong answer... With `nicematrix`, you need several compilations (because the rules are drawn by PGF/Tikz with nodes PGF/Tikz nodes created by `nicematrix`). At the first compilation, usually, no rules are drawn...

Comment: @F.Pantigny, you may be right.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a long table (table spanning multiple pages), you can use `longtblr` from the `tabularray` package and with this, you can use different vertical alignment for different columns, whereas in the case of `longtable`, you can use only one type of vertical alignment.

I didn't know that the text is in French. Borrowed it from the answer of [F. Pantigny](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/618235/219947).

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}
% place the caption in the footer, i.e. below the table
\DefTblrTemplate{head}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{firstfoot}{default}{
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption}{default}
}
\DefTblrTemplate{middlefoot,lastfoot}{default}{
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption}{default} % if table spans multiple pages, change the option `caption` to `capcont`
}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption={Les avantages de la méthodologie OSSTMM },
label={tab:avantages osstmm},
]{
colspec = {|X[7 cm, m, j]|X[8 cm, m, j]|}, %m for vertical alignment, j for justified text
row{1}={bg=black, fg=white, c},
hlines,
vline{2} = {1}{white}, %makes 2nd vertical line in 1st row white
}
\textbf{Avantages} & \textbf{Justification}
\\
Se concentrer sur l’implémentation du plan d’atténuation des vulnérabilités    & Ce plan permet d’assurer que les vulnérabilités sont traitées par des actions spécifiques, mesurables, réalisables, et concrètes. NIST est la seule méthodologie à traiter ce point. 
\\
Aide le testeur à rédiger des rapports périodiques  &  NIST suggère d’écrire un rapport étape par étape, car après chaque planification d’attaque le testeur doit reporter ce qu’il va faire ainsi que les résultats obtenus, ce qui est une bonne pratique si non de nombreux détails tombent dans l’oubli.
\\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yeah actually I need a longtable, thank you.